# Replicating Excel averageifs in PowerBI

Tags: excel-formula, powerbi, average, powerbi-desktop

I'm having difficulty replicating the following Excel calculation in power BI

```
=IFERROR(AVERAGEIFS(Data!$I:$I,Data!$A:$A,Tables!$C$2,Data!$B:$B,Tables!$E$2,Data!$E:$E,Tables!$B5), "N/A")
```

I am trying to calculate an average on 3 values, area, period and metric. In power bi using the quick measure it returns either the count of the metric title or the average of the metric, with an additional row for the values that are marked as n/a.

```
Count of Raw_Score average per metric_ref = 
AVERAGEX(
    KEEPFILTERS(VALUES('Data'[metric_ref])),
    CALCULATE(COUNTA('Data'[Raw_Score]))
)
```

[files / images here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aqw9t5Hm7znwgboS2IeiUdi43KILTA?e=l5raSm)

Answer (score 1):

maybe I understood the question wrong, so feel free to correct me, but you are simply trying to calculate an average for different groups, is that so?

First, when working with PowerBI do yourself a favor and forget how Excel works, your life ll be much easier.

Now for the solution.

The trouble is, that your score metric is not a correct data type for average calculation. In Edit Queries, change data type to number (prior step of replacing "N/A" to "" might be required)

[image]

(optional step) I would recommend fixing data type of all relevant columns.

With data in correct format, you simply create visualization and slice it with grouping label. Something like this:

[image]

Notice the small arrow near the Value-theme_ref field (in your case you should probably substitute it with Raw_Score columns). You simply change the calculation from Sum to Average, which should do the trick.

Once again, I apologize if I misunderstood the question. Feel free to specify.

Comment: Yes you understood correctly. Turns out I was greener than I thought, but this put me on the right path thank you.

I cleaned up the tables and created a couple of reference tables linking them to get the average scores I wanted